# django collectstatic adding extra /static/ folders

Tags: python, django

It's weird that everytime I run collectstatic consecutively it copies the static files to an extra static folder within the static folder:

First time I run it:
`Copying '/var/www/django/abc/public-www/static//images/coro.jpg'`

the second time I run it, it will copy the files as below:
`Copying '/var/www/django/abc/public-www/static/static/images/coro.jpg'`

third time:
`Copying '/var/www/django/abc/public-www/static/static/static/images/coro.jpg'`

This is what I have in settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(__file__))
VIRTUALENV_ROOT = dirname(PROJECT_ROOT)

STATIC_ROOT = join(VIRTUALENV_ROOT, 'public-www', 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the culprit, I had this line for MEDIA_ROOT

```
MEDIA_ROOT = join(VIRTUALENV_ROOT, 'public-www')
```

Which should have been:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = join(VIRTUALENV_ROOT, 'public-www', 'media')
```

Once I changed it, collectstatic works as normal.